# Android 10 shows NFC read error toast when the user attempts to scan NFC tag

Tags: android, nfc, android-10.0

After update to Android 10 we noticed that Android started showing a toast with the following text: "NFC read error. Try again." when we try to scan NFC tag via our app. The message is being shown rather randomly and we can not find a stable way to reproduce it.

I saw the similar reports on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/android_beta/comments/ce2fxi/nfc_read_error/), mentioning that this toast sometimes is shown even when the user does something innocent, like unlocking the screen or opening the Google Messenger app.

I looked in documentation on Android 10 changes and found nothing related to NFC. Is it something which can be resolved?

Comment: Android 10 Documentation does have changes to NFC support but it should not affect card support only NFC Beam (They have deprecating Android Beam)
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-all#beam-deprecation

Answer (score 2):

I was going crazy trying to figure out why this was happening on my Galaxy S10e immediately after the Android 10 update. In my case it turned out to be my tap to pay Visa credit card which sits in my case along with my drivers license. I removed the card and the nfc related notifications have not appeared again. I'll have to go back to carrying one of the dumb ol' credit cards until Samsung resolves this issue.